# Retry on UnavailableException to a different data center

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I'm using the DataStax Cassandra Java driver 2.1.2 to have clients connect to one of three data centers, like so:

.withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("DC1",1)))

This sets DC1 as the local data center, but also has the driver make one connection to the other two remote data centers.

Now if some of the nodes are down in the local data center, the client will fail to get a local quorum on an insert statement, and an UnavailableException will be thrown.  But there are sufficient nodes available in the remote data centers for the insert to get a quorum there and succeed, so I would like the driver to retry the insert in the other data centers.  But how do I tell the driver to do this?

It looks like there is a way to set a RetryPolicy to retry with a lower consistency level, but I don't see anything about retrying to a remote data center.

If all the nodes in DC1 are down, then the driver does try the insert at a remote data center where it succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up getting this to work is I first try the insert with these settings (note that I'm using the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause on the insert):

statement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.*LOCAL_QUORUM*);
statement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.*LOCAL_SERIAL*);

This tells Cassandra to only do the insert if it can get a local quorum for both the "IF NOT EXISTS" check and for the write.  If there aren't enough replicas alive to get a local quorum, I catch the UnavailableException and NoHostAvailableException exceptions and change the consistency level to:

statement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.*QUORUM*);
statement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.*SERIAL*);

Then I try the insert again and this time it will try to get a quorum across all the data centers and succeed.  So with this approach I get decent performance for most inserts by restricting the very expensive "IF NOT EXISTS" check to the local DC, while getting the reliability of not being dead in the water when some of the local replicas are down.